# Eclipse refuses to import an existing project inside workspace

Tags: eclipse, import, intellij-idea, project, eclipse-3.6

I have been creating a servlet based application for past 3 days, and it worked properly and compiled accordingly as expected. But today when I opened to add few more additionals to the same project, Eclipse showed me the project is not available and when I tried to re-import the project it says - No projects are found to import. Below is the screen shot for the same![image]
I have following files inside my project:
1) .idea
2) .settings
3) build
4) src
5) WebContent

What possibly could be the reason, and how should I fix this invisibility.
 Any help would be really helpful.

Thanks!

**EDIT**
    I did tried importing the same project on IDEA a day back too, would that be the reason its not more compatible for eclipse? Also, if I try opening from IDEA IDE it still refuses to import it.

Comment: I think your .project file is missing. I suggest create a new project and copy-paste all your project contents over there.

Comment: @DhrubajyotiGogoi, I guess while importing the same project in IDEA made the eclipse proj an .idea project. But, If I try opening the same in IDEA it doesn't recognize there as well. I guess, I would do the copy-paste thing as suggested. Thank you !!

Comment: .project file is required by eclipse. Probably it was deleted in the process.